# Fast XML parsing with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm parsing an XML file with Ruby and Nokogiri, but I have some problems with execution time. It's taking one minute for 4000 lines - it is too much. I'm trying to find some ideas for code optimisation.

This is an example of the code:

```
input = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(file_name))
input.xpath('//Transition').each do |transition_record|
  from = transition_record.xpath('@From')
  to = transition_record.xpath('@To')
  name = transition_record.xpath('@Name')
  Transition.create do |transition|
    transition.from_id = from.to_s
    transition.to_id = to.to_s
    transition.name = name.to_s

    if transition_record.at_xpath('Condition').at_xpath('@Type')
      transition.condition = transition_record.at_xpath('Condition').at_xpath('@Type').to_s
    end
  end
end
```

`Transition` isn't fixed place in place in the XML and can be at any level.  Also, I'm parsing three other tags in the some way.

Does anybody have any ideas how I can improve it?

Comment: Nokogiri is pretty fast. I would look to your model/db being the problem first.

Comment: I didn't think about it. Really, with postgr instead of litesql everything is better. Thanks!

Comment: For this sort of question it is a great help to supply a small sample of the XML too. Without it you're asking us to infer, or build a working sample from your code, which doesn't work well usually.

Answer (score 0):

You can reorganize your code so that you are creating an array of hashes with Nokogiri, then you can use them directly in `create`. This will allow you to time each part separately. I think you'll find that Nokogiri isn't the problem.